# How to store hierarchy of constants using ENUMs

Tags: java, enums, hashmap, constants

Lets sat we have following hierarchy of constants that I would like to hard code..

```
FRUIT->APPLE->GREEN_APPLE->"Fruit is apple of green color"
FRUIT->APPLE->RED_APPLE->"Fruit is apple of red color"
FRUIT->Cherry->RED_CHERRY->"Fruit is cherry of red color"

FLOWER->ROSE->RED_ROSE->"Flower is rose of red color"
FLOWER->ROSE->PINK_ROSE->"Flower is rose of pink color"
```

Given an input, say FRUIT,APPLE,RED_APPLE, I would like to get "Fruit is apple of red color" as output.

How can I maintain this hierarchy and support the look up? Can it be done using Enums?? or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested `enum` to `String` map.

```
enum E { FRUIT, FLOWER, VEGETABLE}
enum F { APPLE, Cherry, ROSE}
enum G { GREEN_APPLE, RED_APPLE, RED_CHERRY, RED_ROSE, PINK_CHERRY}

static void add(Map<E, Map<F, Map<G, String>>> map, E e, F f, G g, String s) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(e, k -> new HashMap<>())
        .computeIfAbsent(f, k -> new HashMap<>())
        .put(g, s);
}

static String get(Map<E, Map<F, Map<G, String>>> map, E e, F f, G g) {
    return Optional.of(map.get(e))
        .map(m -> m.get(f))
        .map(m -> m.get(g))
        .orElse(null);
}
```

and

```
Map<E, Map<F, Map<G, String>>> map = new HashMap<>();

add(map, E.FRUIT, F.APPLE, G.GREEN_APPLE, "Fruit is apple of green color");
add(map, E.FRUIT, F.APPLE, G.RED_APPLE, "Fruit is apple of red color");
add(map, E.FRUIT, F.Cherry, G.RED_CHERRY, "Fruit is cherry of red color");
add(map, E.FLOWER, F.ROSE, G.RED_ROSE, "Flower is rose of red color");
add(map, E.VEGETABLE, F.ROSE, G.PINK_CHERRY, "Flower is rose of pink color");

System.out.println(get(map, E.FRUIT, F.APPLE, G.GREEN_APPLE));
```

output:

```
Fruit is apple of green color
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using `enum` and `interface`.

```java
public interface Product {
    String getDescription();
}
```

```java
public interface Fruit extends Product{ }
```

```java
public interface Flower extends Product{}
```

```java
public enum Apple implements Fruit{
    GREEN_APPLE("Fruit is apple of green color"),
    RED_APPLE("Fruit is apple of red color");

    private final String description;

    Apple(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

```java
public enum Cherry implements Fruit{
    RED_CHERRY("Fruit is cherry of red color");

    private final String description;

    Cherry(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

```java
public enum Rose implements Flower{

    RED_ROSE("Flower is rose of red color"),
    PINK_CHERRY("Flower is rose of pink color");

    private final String description;

    Rose(String description) {
        this.description=description;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print(Apple.GREEN_APPLE);
        print(Apple.RED_APPLE);
        print(Cherry.RED_CHERRY);
        print(Rose.RED_ROSE);
        print(Rose.PINK_CHERRY);

    }

    public static void print(Product product){
        System.out.println(product.getDescription());
    }

}
```

***Output***

```
Fruit is apple of green color
Fruit is apple of red color
Fruit is cherry of red color
Flower is rose of red color
Flower is rose of pink color
```

**Reference** - https://www.baeldung.com/java-extending-enums#emulate-extensible-enums-with-interfaces